# Rack::MethodOverride#call rails 4 + unicorn + apache slowness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, unicorn

We are experiencing slowness after rails upgrade from Rails 3.2.2 to Rails 4.2 with unicorn 4.8.3 and apache 2.2.15.

Do we need to tweak unicorn w.r.t Rails?[image: Image display the Rack::Methodoverride#call taking 98%]

[image: Trace details]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?